# Why does gdal.translate not accept a third argument?

Tags: python, gdal

According to the docs, gdal.Translate should accept three arguments. The code snippet below is copied directly from the definition file gdal.py

```
 def Translate(destName, srcDS, **kwargs):
```

My function call looks like this :

```
 gdal.Translate(tileName, rasterfile, options)
```

My IDE ( VScode) instantly notices that something is off, and tells me that ther are too many arguemnts given. Running the code leads to the following error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):  File
>   "c:/Users/parejo/Desktop/tile_gen.py", line 24, in 
>       gdal.Translate(tileName, rasterfile, options) TypeError: Translate() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

What am I missing here?

Code itself is fine, if i remove the `options` argument, everything runs smoothly, but as i am missing my options, i dont get the results i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call with this (didnt tested code)

```
gdal.Translate(tileName, rasterfile, *options)
```

Comment: this is almost right, i called like this :
``` 
gdal.Translate(tileName, rasterfile, **options)
```
Which made the call work, now it crashed because my options are of the wrong format, but regarding the call itself things work now.

Answer (score 2):

```py
def Translate(destName, srcDS, **kwargs):
```

means the function accepts a variable number of [keyword arguments](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-keywordargs), which it may interpret at its leisure.

If you have a dict, e.g.

```py
options = {"something": true}
```

or something more dynamically generated, and you wish to pass it in, you can unpack it into keyword arguments with the same `**` syntax when calling the function:

```py
gdal.Translate(tileName, rasterfile, **options)
```

When you don't need to dynamically adjust the keyword arguments, it's more Pythonic to just pass them in:

```py
gdal.Translate(tileName, rasterfile, something=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
options = {
    'destName': tileName,
    'srcDS': rasterfile,
    # kwargs options
}
gdal.Translate(**options)
```